# Mysql JOIN condition on another JOIN's statement results

Tags: mysql

I need your help because JOINs are a headache for me and I am trying to use them as little as possible but that is not always easy...

I have these tables:

Transit table

```
Number, company, status
```

Subscription table

```
Userid, number, name
```

Event table

```
Number, event_type
```

Since now I used this query to get some info from 2 tables (transit and subscription) based on the conditions below (status = intransit and userid = 1):

```
SELECT transit.status, transit.company, subscription.name
FROM transit
    JOIN subscription ON transit.number = subscription.number 
        AND transit.status = 'intransit' 
        AND subscription.userid = 1
```

I don't know if it is the most efficient or correct but it worked.

Now I also want to add another condition but from a 3rd table.
So I want the previous results to be norrowed down if the event_type = 1 (from the Event table). The only common value between the 3rd table and the results is the number.
How can I add something like "AND event.event_id = 1" to the previous results so I get only those who satisfy that as well?

-edit-
Since i tried the solution proposed below and to help others, for example the results are

```
12345 | companyA | intransit
56789 | companyB | intransit
39494 | companyC | intransit
58328 | companyB | intransit
```

but only number 56789 has event_type = 1 on the Event table, so I want only

```
56789 | companyB | intransit
```

to be returned. With the proposed query it returns

```
56789 | companyB | intransit
56789 | companyB | intransit
56789 | companyB | intransit
```

which is 3 times the correct row (as the rows NOT having the event_type = 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT transit.status, transit.company, subscription.name
FROM transit
    JOIN subscription ON transit.number = subscription.number 
        AND transit.status = 'intransit' 
        AND subscription.userid = 1
    JOIN event ON event.number = transcript.number
        AND event.event_type = 1
```

docs for inner join [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html)

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry did not see your answer

Comment: I had already tried that because it was the obvious thing to try but it returns 3 times the same results: intransit, company_name_here, name_here (x3). If you remove the last JOIN, it returns 4 results. One of them should only be shown using this JOIN as only this has event_type = 1

Comment: @MerNion can you try INNER JOIN and tell me what you get

Comment: Also can you let me know if for a number can there be multiple events?Because JOIN's create a product so if multiple instances in event this is possible.If possible show your tables please

Comment: @MerNion Can you tell me the result of SELECT event.number FROM event WHERE event.number = 56789

Comment: OMG That was it!! It had 3 duplicate events for the same number on the events table! That is why!! I never thought of that! Thanks! Can I somehow get only one result though as they are similar? Distinct or something?

Comment: Yes use SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer even though RiggsFolly answered first because it was very close and you helped me with the comments, plus you need some reputation, he has a lot :) Thank you both though!